# Serialize any Object

Tags: java

I tried doing this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
o.writeObject(obj);
```

Where obj is a simple class I made:

```
class Car {
  int id;
  String color;
  //... 
}
```

However I get `java.io.NotSerializableException`

Is it possible to serialize just about any kind of `java.lang.Object` into `byte array`? Is so, how?

**Update:**

The class that will be "serialized" does not implement a `Serializable` interface; the idea behind this thing I am trying to do is that I'm trying to have a Databse-backed `java.util.Map` where objects `put` in the map are stored directly in the database, thus any kind of `Object`

I have also seen some Serialization framework, where to get around this "limitation" in serializing arbitrary Object, there is a class registration like:

```
kryo.register(SomeClass.class, 0);
```

Not sure about this.

But what I'm quite sure is that I need to do:

- Reflection to read fields and methods of an Object

Comment: Check out google GSON - it could be of use? https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: just add implements Serializable to your Car object

Comment: [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html) serialization specification

Answer (score 3):

Your `Car` class needs to implement the `Serializable` interface for you to be able to `Serialize` your object.

```
class Car implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Can't do this, my application needs to handle any kind of Object

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use a java.io.ObjectOutputStream to serialize every `Object`.

From the javadoc of [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams.

If you absolutely need java objects serialization [kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/#Quickstart) worths a try. By default you just need to do:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
// ...
Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("file.bin"));
SomeClass someObject = ...
kryo.writeObject(output, someObject);
output.close();
```

Kryo doesn't require your classes to implement `Serializable` and you can provide separate [Serializer](http://kryo.googlecode.com/svn/api/v2/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/Serializer.html) for your classes to control the serialization form. But is optional.

The code `kryo.register(SomeClass.class, 0);` is optional too, it optimize the serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

here comes generic ObjectSerializer for serialize/deserialize  (adapted from Apache libs):

```
public class ObjectSerializer {

    private static final String TAG = "ObjectSerializer";

    public static String serialize(Serializable obj) {// throws IOException {
        if (obj == null) return "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
            objStream.writeObject(obj);
            objStream.close();
            return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Serialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            Log.e(TAG, "Serialization error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str) {// throws IOException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
            ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
            return objStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Deserialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            Log.e(TAG, "Deserialization error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        }

        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
            c = str.charAt(i+1);
            bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

Comment: Neat code, however, it is limited to Serializable object, I need an implementation that can serialize java.lang.Object (not really Serializable type)

Comment: maybe i'm wrong but practically Object has to be Serializable to be able to use for such purpose. aka "implements Serializable"